# Searching (Filtering) on multi models using drf-haystack searchindex and elasticsearch

Tags: django-haystack

I have been trying to implement multiple models using rdf-haystack filters but it does not work. Here are my examples:
I have two models search_indexes.py

```
class PersonSkillIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
   text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
   person_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='person_id')
   skill_name = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='skill_id')

   autocomplete = indexes.EdgeNgramField()
   @staticmethod

   def prepare_autocomplete(obj):
   return " ".join((obj.skill_id.name)) 

   def get_model(self):
   return PersonSkill

   def index_queryset(self, using=None):
   return self.get_model().objects.all()

   def prepare_person_id(self, obj):
   return obj.person_id.name

   def prepare_skill_id(self, obj):
   return obj.skill_id.name

class PersonPositionIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
   text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
   person_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='person_id')
   position_name = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='position_id')
   autocomplete = indexes.EdgeNgramField()

   @staticmethod
   def prepare_autocomplete(obj):
   return " ".join(( obj.position_id.title)) 

   def get_model(self):
   return PersonPosition 

   def index_queryset(self, using=None):
   return self.get_model().objects.all()

   def prepare_person_id(self, obj):
   return obj.person_id.name

   def prepare_position_id(self, obj):
   return obj.position_id.name
```

I want to search on both PersonSkill and PersonPosition models with the following searchQuerySet:

```
http://localhost:8000/en/api/profiles/search/?skill_name=python&position_name=programmer
```

Does Haytack filters support this functionality? if Any suggestions will be welcomed!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please go through

http://drf-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/09_multiple_indexes.html

This post describes a way similar to what you are looking.

Basically you can specify a list of indexes in 'index_classes' attribute.

This can be useful when your search engine has indexed multiple models and you want to provide aggregate results across two or more of them. To use the default multiple index support, simply add multiple indexes the index_classes list.